# PyDev selected source folder is not recognized as a valid source folder

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, pydev

I followed the PyDev install tutorial from pydev.org and still can't set up a new packaged source folder - I'm constantly faced with the error message "the selected source folder is not recognized as a valid source folder".

Comment: Can you add a screenshot for that? What exactly are you doing that gives you this message?

Answer (score 5):

Set the folder as a source folder first by right clicking the folder and selecting "Set as Source Folder (add to PYTHONPATH)"

then you can create packages in there.